# Reading JSON with Terraform jsondecode failing for valid JSON file

Tags: python, json, terraform

I have a JSON file in S3 which looks like this:

```
{
  "data_sources": [
    {
      "name": "monzo",
      "tables": [
        "transactions"
      ],
      "format": "CSV",
      "extension": "csv"
    }
  ]
}
```

and I am trying to read it in Terraform with this

```
...
data_sources = jsondecode(data.aws_s3_bucket_object.data_sources.body)
...
```

and it is throwing this error:

```
╷
│ Error: Invalid function argument
│ 
│   on variables.tf line 41, in locals:
│   41:   data_sources = jsondecode(data.aws_s3_bucket_object.data_sources.body)
│     ├────────────────
│     │ while calling jsondecode(str)
│     │ data.aws_s3_bucket_object.data_sources.body is null
│ 
│ Invalid value for "str" parameter: argument must not be null.
```

However, if I save the file and auto-format it in VSCode, making it look like this:

```
{
  "data_sources": [
    {
      "name": "monzo",
      "tables": ["transactions"],
      "format": "CSV",
      "extension": "csv"
    }
  ]
}
```

Terraform can read it and everything works.

The data is

```
data "aws_s3_bucket_object" "data_sources" {
  bucket = "my_bucket"
  key    = "data_sources.json"
}
```

Why is this happening? And how can I create that file in Python in such a way that Terraform can read it? I'm creating it from a dict (`converted_data`) like so

```
json.dumps(converted_data, indent=2)
```

Comment: So the data source is actually providing you with a return value?

Comment: What does `terraform console` return for `data.aws_s3_bucket_object.data_sources.body` ?

Comment: Only `(known after apply)`

Comment: Not sure what you meant @MarkoE?

Comment: The same thing @Paolo asked. :)

Comment: Do you get the error at plan time or apply time?

Comment: At plan time...

Comment: @mcansado what is the content type of the object you are trying to fetch from the bucket?

Comment: @MarkoE First comment is correct answer: `data.aws_s3_bucket_object.data_sources` is not returning the expected result (and almost certainly is returning nothing). We need to see the relevant `data` config to assist further.

Comment: Edited to add that @MattSchuchard but I don't think that should be the problem since everything works when I save the file and re-upload it...

Comment: @mcansado what is the Content-Type of the file when you look at the file from the bucket?

Comment: Just json as it would be expected.

Comment: And the path is the full path to the object?

Comment: Yes. Again it reads it when I reupload with the same name... I think it's something in the JSON itself.